# JavaScript Text Replace

Tags: javascript, text, replace

I'm using the code below to amend an image url (basically adding 'admin' to the start of the URL inside 'news' div. This works fine for what I'm trying to do, but it's causing some other problems, like blocking embedded Tweets and blocking some adverts from showing that are placed inside the 'news' div.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want that won't impact other code as I can't for the life of me understand why it's causing issues with other code, but removing the below fixes the issue with the tweets and ads?

```
function replaceText(){
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("news");
    var theText = theDiv .innerHTML;

    theText = theText.replace(/ckfinder/g, 'admin/ckfinder');

    theDiv.innerHTML = theText;
}
```

This is the image path I'm amending:

```
<img height="267" src="/ckfinder/userfiles/images/XXX/XXX.jpg" width="400" />
```

But need it to be:

```
<img height="267" src="admin/ckfinder/userfiles/images/XXX/XXX.jpg" width="400" />
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell without looking at what it breaks. The only way to solve this is to find a pattern that applies to the cases where you want the replacement to apply and does not apply to the ones where you don't want it. It's as simple as that. If, for example, other elements have this in href's, you could replace `src="/ckfinder/` with `src="admin/ckfinder/`. Or use a regex and only make the replacement for image files. In short, it's impossible to provide an answer to your question based on currently available information.

Comment: Can you find enough specific differences between wanted and unwanted replacements so they are separated without exception? If you don't know how to code them, describe the differences and someone will help you put it in code form, as you already showed minimal research effort (a reasonable attempt at coding this yourself).

Comment: Perhaps by also including the forward slashes in the regex?  f.e.`theText = theText.replace(/\"\/ckfinder\//g, '\"admin/ckfinder/');`

Comment: You should be updating the `src` attribute not the HTML inside the tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be more specific and target the `img` tag and update the `src` attribute directly.

```js
function replaceText() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".news img");

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = images[i];
    img.src = img.src.replace(/ckfinder/g, 'admin/ckfinder');
  }
}


window.onload = replaceText;
```

```html
<div id="news">

  <p>Don't want to update this ckfinder</p>

  <img height="267" src="/ckfinder/userfiles/images/XXX/XXX.jpg" width="400" />

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. I just had to amend the div to a class though. Thank you!

Comment: @RyanW Cool, if it worked then please accept this answer :o)